# How to convert .obj files to .sfb file programmatically in Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arcore, sceneform

I am working on an AR project that we are generating real-time 3D models (.obj files) online based on many factors. Unfortunately, I am not being able to convert .obj files with gradle and upload them to the server.

I was wondering if anybody knows how .sfb files are formatted (I did the research but couldn't find any solution) so that we can generate .sfb files in our server, or optionally a way or algorithm that can help me to convert .obj files to .sfb files programmatically.

Comment: I believe `SFB` files are closed-source and generally tied to SDK versions (as the internals can/do change). Did you see this closed issue regarding using the plugin: [Load SFB at runtime (without Sceneform plugin/gradle combo)](https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/issues/636)